# Formal algorithms for edit buffer memory allocation

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, text-editor

I'm writing a Roslyn-driven C# editor. Roslyn syntax verification requires me to submit the entire edit buffer of a C# source file for analysis every time a keystroke is pressed. The buffer has to be a snapshot, so I can't wrap the actual live edit buffers.

The current algorithm, waiting for the "Never Optimize" rule to expire: Allocate a fresh char[] array every keystroke, and serialize the editor text into the array, pay no attention to what the actual operation was.

Surprisingly, the performance isn't terrible. But I'm worried about thrashing the garbage collector with large allocations in large projects. Imagine allocating a 2MB buffer every keystroke while editing a large C# file. That can't be good in the long term.

I know from an inside source that Visual Studio uses some sort of "binary tree" data structure to submit incremental updates. But the sources for that part of Visual Studio aren't available.

I imagine an algorithm something along the lines of: split the entire edit buffer up into manageably small pieces. A change to the document will either insert, delete or replace one or more characters every time a key is pressed. So instead of allocating a fresh buffer, use a strategy that splits and patches in changes; then wrap the entire data structure with a an interfaces that presents the fragments as a contiguous sequential block. Instead of allocating massive large-object structures, that are going to force a Gen2 CG, allocate little tiny blocks to effect the patch.

And presumably some strategy for coalescing, maybe on a lowest-priority thread.

I could go at it adhoc, but I can't help thinking there must be some formal algorithm to deal with this problem.

Anyone? (A pair of swapped buffers, I suppose. But still...)

Answer (score 2):

There are three main data structures that I know of used for text editor buffers, Gap Buffer, Piece table and rope data structure. The tree structure you describe could apply to either a rope data structure or piece table but is not required for a piece table.

There is an number of articles on rope data structures available at https://xi-editor.io/xi-editor/docs/rope_science_00.html by a google employee that are quite good and are programming language independent, (the xi editor itself is written in rust).

A piece table (https://darrenburns.net/posts/piece-table/) can be implemented as a tree data structure but also could simply be an array of strings for each line of the file and in fact this is what VS Code did until around 2018.

A Gap buffer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer) is probably the simplest approach and can be fast enough for a lot of use cases but will suffer when used on large text files due to potentially large memory copies.

I'm unfamiliar with the Roslyn API but keeping track of the edits in one of the above structures and then building a complete version when you submit the text buffer to Roslyn on a background thread sounds reasonable at least.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant algorithms: splay trees, red-black trees.

The following article describes the implementation used by visual studio

https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2018/03/23/text-buffer-reimplementation

A red-black tree containing buffers that can be split into pieces, with a caveat that their piece buffers eventually fragment because they make no attempt to consolidate.

The implementation is.... ferociously difficult and I have grave concerns about correctness. :-) Modifying the already toxicly difficult red-black tree algorithm to be text-position based is.... really really hard.

I'm currently wondering whether O(n) insertion complexity is so terrible given that I'm going to immediately turn around and feed the result to a C# parser that is optimistically O(n log(n)) for processing.

Comment: you can use a doubly-linked list to hold pieces for a piece table structure as well, instead of a tree. And if you do opt for a tree, up until a certain point something closer to a plain binary search tree would still provide good performance.